# Can I use word "entry" to describe persons who registered/entered for a program

Tags: word-request

There'are some volunteer programs, allow local students to register for. once their registration are approved, they can contribute there services.

How can I use a word (e.g. `entry`) to describe those people who are registered ?

Possible usage:

> There're 3 `entries` for program XXX. (There're 3 people registered in XXX program)

According to dictionary:

> Entry: **list or total number of persons,etc.entered for a competition**

I am not sure if this word can be used out of competition.

=========== UPDATED ==========

Perhaps the word `volunteer` is OK for this senario, but I'd like to emphasize the status of being "Registered", may `applicant` ? `registrant` be ok ?

Comment: [*Participants*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/participant), perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "entry" in this sense is mostly limited to contests and games of chance. You can say, "There were 3 entries for the 50-meter race" or "There were 300 entries for the lottery", but we don't say, "Our company has 20 entries" meaning 20 employees, nor an example like yours, "We asked for volunteers to help at the food pantry and got 20 entries."

More likely words would be "volunteers" if they're not paid, "participants" as Mick suggests in a comment, or "workers". Or something more specific to the task, like if they're teaching other students you might say "tutors", if they're painting the building you might say "painters", etc.

Comment: I updated my question. Perhaps the word volunteer is OK for this senario, but I'd like to emphasize the status of being "Registered", may applicant ? registrant be ok ? @Jay

Comment: Yes, you could say "registrant". I think "registration" would be more idiomatic: "We have 5 registrations for this program". Or well it's longer, I think fluent speakers would be more likely to say, "Five people have registered for this program."

Answer (score 2):

**[Entrant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entrant)** is used to refer to people.

> a person who enters something (such as a competition)

There were 5000 entrants in the marathon.